# C# Class Library, Cannot register App.Manifest with details for 3rd party DLLs

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, manifest

I'm building a Prism WPF application and the main module loads a custom control for each device on the network. The custom control uses 3rd party Libraries from an SDK. The SDK is installed on the client machine in the application folder as a standalone installation as recommend by the SDK distributor to avoid future compatibility problems with other applications that also use the same SDK.

This SDK has a folder structure inside my application root folder and so the DLLs are not directly in the application root folder but in sub-folders.

A manifest file in the WPF application Shell allows my application to find the SDK DLLs in the sub-folders but my Custom control does not find the DLLs. If I manually place the DLLs my Custom Control needs into the application root folder on the client machine then my custom control works.

So basically, the main application uses the manifest but the Custom Control library doesn't.
The Custom Control is using Windows Forms Intergeneration to load an active X control in the main Prism module and display it in the WPF application.

Can I add an app.manifest to my Custom Control class library? ( GOOGLE says NO ).
Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

On further inspection it's obvious that 2 of DLL's the Custom Control needs are not in the SDK and placing just these 2 DLL's into the Application root solves my issue. This means the Class library is using the Manifest to find the common DLL's in the SDK folder structure.